# Ogre3d Local reference string popping out of nowhere

Tags: xcode, macos, ogre3d

I'm building an ogre3d tutorial based on this setup
http://www.ogre3d.org/wiki/index.php/SettingUpAnApplication#XCode

I've followed all steps as it says. It compiled perfectly.

But on run this happened:

```
*-*-* OGRE Initialising
*-*-* Version 1.6.0 (Shoggoth)
Creating resource group Bootstrap
An exception has occurred: OGRE EXCEPTION(7:InternalErrorException): /Users/fmsf/Chalmers/SimulationEngines/testes/OgreProject/build/Debug/OgreProject.app//Users/fmsf/Chalmers/SimulationEngines/ogr3d/OgreSDK/Samples/Media/packs/OgreCore.zip - error whilst opening archive: Unable to read zip file. in ZipArchive::checkZzipError at /Users/steve/projects/Shoggoth_clean/ogre/Mac/Ogre/../../OgreMain/src/OgreZip.cpp (line 259)
*-*-* OGRE Shutdown
```

The `/Users/fmsf/...` are mine, but that string `/Users/steve/projects...` I have no clue where it is coming from as I've reviewed the configuration files and can't find it anywhere.

Anyone have a clue how to fix this? It is the very first time I am using ogre so I feel a bit lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unknown filename might just be a compiled-in part of the code that detects an error; it points out a C++ source file. According to [this page](http://www.ogre3d.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=12&Itemid=129), the lead developer of Ogre3d is named Steve Streeting ...

Check the archive, is it listable (with `zip -v`) and otherwise sane-looking? If so, there could be some kind of version conflict between it and Ogre3D's zip-reading code, perhaps.